# Node.js - JWT, API: How To Implement Multiple Passport.js Authentication Middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js, middleware

So I am trying to build two JWT authentication systems for one app. One for the users and one for businesses. The authentication uses passport (local and JWT). I started working on the user aspect of the authentication and I was able to make it work as I wanted. I thought it would be the same for business. All I did was simply copy paste and change few variable. Normally the business endpoints should work but it does not. So I tried to debug what was going on and I am still trying to figure out what it is. My guess is that when I load the strategies in my app.js, only the passport strategies for users get called. If I permute positions between `passport` and `business-passport`, everything breaks.

Here is my code.

**Passport Middleware For User** passport.js

```
const passport = require('passport');
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const {ExtractJwt} = require('passport-jwt');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const { JWT_SECRET } = require('./config');
const User = require('./models/user');
// const Business = require('./models/business');

passport.use(new JwtStrategy({
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    secretOrKey: JWT_SECRET,
    passReqToCallback: true
}, async (req, payload, done) => {
    console.log('payload', payload)

    try {
        // Find the user specified in token
        const user = await User.findById(payload.sub);

        // Handle if User dont exist
        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false);
        }

        // Otherwise, return the user
        req.user = user;
        done(null, user);
    } catch (error) {
        done(error, false);
    }

}));
// Local Strategy
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
}, async (email, password, done) => {

    try {
        // Find the user given the email
        const user = await User.findOne({email});

        // If not, handle it
        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false);
        }

        // check if password is correct

        const isMatch = await user.isValidPassword(password);

        // if not, handle it
        if (!isMatch) {
            return done(null, false);
        }

        // Otherwise, return the user
        done(null, user);

    } catch (error) {
        done(error, false);
    }

}));
```

**Passport Middleware For Business**  passport-business.js

Just change User for Business

**Controllers for Users**  controllers/user.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const JWT = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { JWT_SECRET } = require('../config');

const User = require('../models/user');

signToken = user => {
    // Respond with token
    return JWT.sign({
        iss: 'My Business, Inc.',
        userType: 'users',
        sub: user._id, /* You can also use newUser.id */
        iat: new Date().getTime(), /* Current Time */
        exp: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1), /* Current Time + 1 day ahead */
    }, JWT_SECRET);
};

module.exports = {

    signup: async (req, res, next) => {
        console.log('req.value.body', req.value.body);

        const {email, password} = req.value.body;

        // Check if User already exist by email address
        const foundUser = await User.findOne({email});
        if(foundUser) {
            return res.status(403).json({error: 'Email is already in use'});
        }

        // Create a new User
        const newUser = new User({email, password});
        await newUser.save();

        // Generate the token
        const token = signToken(newUser);

        // Respond with token
        res.status(200).json({token});
    },
    signin: async (req, res, next) => {
        // Generate token
        const token = signToken(req.user);
        res.status(200).json({token});
        // console.log('signin');
    },
};
```

The reason why I have `req.value...` is because of a middleware that I used to validate my body and url params.

**Controllers for Business**  controllers/business.js . 
Everything is the same, just change User with Business.

I should also point out that whenever I use jwt.io to see if my token signature is valid, it always says `invalid signature`, but everything works on my application as expected. Wondering why it is saying `invalid signature`.

**Routes for Users** routes/user.js . Please remember that it is the same for Business.

```
const express = require('express');

// this router deals better with "try{} catch{}" situations"
const router = require('express-promise-router')();

const passport = require('passport');

const UserController = require('../controllers/user');

require('../passport');

const { validateBody, schemas, validateParam } = require('../helpers/route-helpers');

const StrategyLocal = passport.authenticate('local', {session: false});
const StrategyJWT = passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {

    res.json({message: "Welcome to our User's API Endpoint!"});
});

router.route('/signup')
    // .get(UserController.index)
    .post([validateBody(schemas.authSchema)], UserController.signup);
router.route('/signin')
    // Makes sense to implement localstrat here because jWt will always work because the user was issued a token at signup
    // So both solutions will work here as a strategy
    .post(validateBody(schemas.authSchema), StrategyLocal, UserController.signin);

module.exports = router;
```

And finally, the file that I think is causing the problem... Introducing...
**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const logger = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');

const { dbName } = require('./config');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/' + dbName, {
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
});

const app = express();

//  This is where the problem is happening in my opinion
require('./passport-business')
require('./passport')


const user = require('./routes/user');
const business = require('./routes/business');

// Middlewares
// set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, noauth");
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false);
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
});

app.use('/api/users', user);
app.use('/api/businesses', business);


// Start the server

const port =  app.get('port') || 2019;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`));
```

If I keep everything as is, all User endpoints work, signup works for Business, but I get 401 when I try to signin (Business). But if I do this...

```
require('./passport')
require('./passport-business')
```

I get 401 when I try to signin (User) and I get 500 when I try to signin (Business).
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? Maybe it is the order in which I load these files in app.js. Maybe it is the fact that I am creating two separate `passport` files for User and Business. **I would love to know how to combine those two into one.** .

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to encode a "type" into the JWT, reuse one middleware and some logic depending on the type?

Comment: Hey Max. If you could elaborate with a little bit of code, that will be helpful. But that is one of my problems; How to encapsulate both passport middlewares into one file, on top of the issues I am having.

Comment: Could it be that I am testing both user and business on the same computer and server, which might be creating conflicts in sessions? I am not sure but this has been frustrating and I still can't move forward with my project. I really do need some help here please.

Comment: It also seems like whenever I call one of the endpoints (`/api/users` or `/api/businesses`) it randomly pick one of the passport files to execute without taking into account the type of users making the call

Answer (score 1):

So in `passport.js` you do this:

```
try {
    // Find the user specified in token
    const user = await User.findById(payload.sub);

    // Handle if User dont exist
    if (!user) {
        return done(null, false);
    }

    // Otherwise, return the user
    req.user = user;
    done(null, user);
} catch (error) {
    done(error, false);
}
```

Instead of cloning the file, couldn't you get `userType` that you're already signing into the JWT and make a conditional?

ie:

```
try {
    // Find the user specified in token
    let user = null;
    if (payload.userType === 'user') {
      user = await User.findById(payload.sub);
    }
    if (payload.userType === 'business') {
      user = await Business.findById(payload.sub);
    }

    // Handle if User dont exist
    if (!user) {
        return done(null, false);
    }

    // Otherwise, return the user
    req.user = user;
    done(null, user);
} catch (error) {
    done(error, false);
}
```

Then were you require two passport files, you'd require just the one

Comment: Hey Max, Thanks for your answer. How would you go about dealing with `passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
},` ? How do you include `payload` here in order to do the same thing as with JWT?